# HTML5 Email validation should not allow email without "." example "aaa@aaa"

Tags: html, email-validation

Basic HTML 5 form, trying to fire HTML 5 email validation which should not allow `"aaa@aaa"` type of emails, meaning those emails which don't have `"."` near the end.

so emails like below are correct

```
asd@asd.com
aaa@aaa.co.in
```

and email like below are incorrect

```
aaa@aaa
```

```html
<form>
      <h2>Email Validation</h2>
      <input type="email" value="" placeholder="name@email.com" required />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<input type="email" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" />`

Comment: why is wrong? please explain and when does it fail?

Comment: That's an extremely long list, but the very first thing I noticed is that it only allows Latin characters and 0-9, so that excludes more than half of the world. Second is that it only allows TLDs of 2-4 characters, while the maximum length is 63, and there are currently TLDs of more than 20 characters.